# how to disabled the system change date & time properties

Tags: vb6

I have developed the vb application .In this ,i want to disabled the system date & time change properties . when my application screen is running then user can not change the system date & time between my application.
how to disabled the system change date & time properties through coding and when my application close it will be enabled ?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System functions do not belong to your application.

Long story short, you should not disable Windows system date editing functionality from within your application even if you could.

What kind of application issues are caused by modifying the system date?

Comment: http://clock-lock.windows-computer-software.com/ download this exe & check the clock of the system ,i want like this

Comment: I repeat: Your application should not take over system functions.